# How to filter record in sql

Tags: sql

I have a list of record in my table:

```
emp_id    emp_status   emp_date
 0001     P            1/1/2012
 0001     P             3/1/2014
 0001     P             4/1/2015  
 0001     R             3/1/2016
```

Let say R = resign and P = present. In this table, I am trying to write a function to get the serve year. One thing I am struggling with now is I am able to get the first Present day (1/1/2012) for this employee and pass it in @join_Date. However, when I am looping at this record (using cursor), the second P date replaced the first one, but I only want the first join date as 1/1/2012. but now my join date is 3/1/2014. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Code is provided

```
    Declare @join_date datetime
    Declare myCursor Cursor for
    Select * From t_emp_info    where emp_id = @emp_id
    order by emp_date desc

        SET @result = 0
    SET @join_date = null

     OPEN myCursor

         FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @emp_date, @emp_status
     IF @emp_status = 'P' AND @join_date IS null 

        //Logic
         Begin
            Set @join_date = @emp_date
     End 
     IF  @emp_status = 'R' AND @join_date IS NOT null

        //Logic

   End
```

Expected Result:

@join_date =  1/1/2012

Actual Result:
@join_date = 3/1/2016

Comment: Where do you assign the value into join_date?

Comment: In the First If statement, I have updated the code

Comment: And is there other places that touches join_date ? Try placing it before the cursor declaration maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors should be avoided wherever possible as they are generally less efficient that set-based operations.

If you are looking for the first date for each employee, group the rows by employee id, order by date, and then select the first result. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, 
    emp_date AS join_date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id order by emp_date) as rn
FROM t_emp_info
WHERE emp_status = 'P' AND rn = 1
```

You could do a similar query to find the retirement date for each employee.

If employees can leave and rejoin, and you preferentially take the last rejoining date, then do something like this:

```
;WITH ORDERED AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_date) as rn
    FROM t_emp_info
), REJOINING AS
(
    SELECT P.* 
    FROM ORDERED R
        LEFT JOIN ORDERED P ON P.rn = R.rn + 1
    WHERE R.emp_status='R' AND P.emp_status='P'
)
SELECT
    P1.emp_id,
    MAX(ISNULL(P2.emp_date,P1.emp_date)) AS join_date
FROM ORDERED P1
    LEFT JOIN REJOINING P2 ON P2.rn > P1.rn
WHERE P1.emp_status='P' AND rn = 1
GROUP BY P1.emp_id
```

Comment: umm, what if I have a record like PPRPP ? Like employee resign in the middle and come back ? I want to take the first first P after the R.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this value by using aggregate function, like this:

```
select emp_id, min(emp_date) as join_date from t_emp_info i where emp_status='P' group by emp_id;
```

or, for single employee:

```
select min(emp_date) as join_date from t_emp_info i where emp_id=@emp_id and emp_status='P';
```